# In Go/http/transport，how to set up proxy with DialTLS?

Tags: go, proxy, tls1.2

I want to modify ClientHello content with [utls](https://github.com/refraction-networking/utls), and I try to use utls with http.Transport. But the DialTLS says it's for non-proxied HTTPS requests, I want to request with utls and proxy. How can I do that? How to make DialTLS for proxied HTTPS requests?

```
// DialTLS specifies an optional dial function for creating
// TLS connections for non-proxied HTTPS requests.
DialTLS func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error)
```